# UIImageView AspectFill failing

Tags: ios, uiimageview, calayer

I'm rendering a 16:9 pixel image programatically and then use `UIImageView` with `kCAFilterNearest` filter and `.ScaleAspectFill` content mode to display it as a background image. The result I get is this:

[image]

On the picture you can see that, for whatever reason, it scales the picture exactly right but slightly moves it up (like, half a scaled pixel) and leaves a line at the bottom, which belongs to the `UIImageView` that the image is displayed on (it's the only view on this `UIViewController` and its background color is "navy").

What might be the reason behind this, considering that I use `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` rectangle for the `UIImageView`?

P.S. `ScaleToFill` content mode gives kind of the same result (the line at the bottom remains)

Answer (score 0):

I use a function to resize the image to fit on the screen

```
fnc imageResize (imageObj:UIImage, sizeChange:CGSize)-> UIImage{

   let hasAlpha = false
   let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen

   UIGraphicsBeginImageCOntextWithOptions(sizeChange, !hasAlpha, scale)
   imageObj.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size : sizeChange))

   let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
   retunr scaledImage
}
```

and to call

```
let mainScreenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let image: UIImage! = self.imageResize(UIImage(named: "IMAGE_NAME")!, sizeChange: CGSizeMake(mainScreenSize.width, mainScreenSize.height))
```

the initial image that I used was 16:9 ratio as well

Comment: That does not exactly answer my question and I know how to simulate a fix, though I appreciate your effort.